# What is the largest deficit overcome in a 6 nations match?

Tags: trivia, statistics, rugby-union

Team A is losing by X points.

At the end of the game, either they draw or Team A wins.

Which is the largest X?

Comment: The way I worded it, it looks like an elementary school test, lol.

Comment: Is this [X](http://s3.amazonaws.com/picable/2007/09/15/59467_Wheres-X_400.jpg)?

Comment: Edited title to say "deficit" rather than "disadvantage". Hope this helps someone answer this because it took me a while to figure out what @Lohoris was asking before. Also I have been looking for this answer and cannot find anything! Weird.

Comment: I would have used the term "comeback" but that's just me.. Relating to the question at hand, all I found was a 12 point comeback for Wales against Scotland: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/rugbyunion/article-1250756/SIX-NATIONS-2010-Wales-31-Scotland-24-Is-greatest-comeback-history-Six-Nations.html I doubt it's the largest deficit in the history of rugby :)

Comment: Is this question restricted just to Six Nations? Or should it include Five Nations and/or any of the previous versions of the tournament?

Comment: @Johno I'd restrict it to 6 nations, if such a data exists...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the question includes a draw as the result, the biggest deficit is now 24 points.

At half-time on Saturday March 16th 2019, Scotland were 31-7 down to England at Twickenham. They overcame the deficit with 31 unanswered points before England scored a converted try in the last phase of the match to draw 38-38.

Answer (score 6):

I can 100% confirm these two as being the equal highest from 2009-2013:

2011: [Italy v France; 6-18 at 50 minutes; 22-21 (12 points)](http://www.espnscrum.com/sixnations2011/rugby/match/114126.html)

2010: [Wales v Scotland; 9-21 at 40 minutes; 31-24 (12 points)](http://www.espnscrum.com/sixnations/rugby/match/94946.html)

Data from 2008 and beforehand only shows the half time score and full time score, which may exclude some comebacks that are larger than this, but none exist from half time, so with the data available, the above is the record. Sometimes if you can't find a statistic, you have to work it out manually yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Wales came back to win 19-24 vs France, after trailing 16-0 at halftime during 6 Nations 2019. I believe this is now the biggest defict.

Comment: I honestly don't understand why this is getting downvotes and delete votes. While it wasn't brilliantly formatted before it was fixed up, I think it's factually correct and a good answer to the question.